# How to apply regularization to LSTM in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to apply **L2 regularization** to my LSTM model. My problem is that I cannot **access the weigths** of the graph to compute the L2 norm from.

I am using an **Estimator** instance to which I pass a **model function** as argument to build the graph.
In my model function I create an LSTM cell with `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell` wrapped into a`static_rnn` .
Now I would like to add L2 regularization into the loss but I don't know how to access the LSTM weights.

My problem is that I **cannot print anything**.
I do not know the name of the **graph variables** but I cannot print them because the model will **not be generated** because I don't know the name of the variable to feed to `tf.nn.l2_loss()`.

How can I access the LSTM weights ? By calling `tf.trainable_variables()` ? `tf.get_variable()` ?

More generally, how can I **print information about a graph** I am trying to create before actually being ready to create it ?

Please be specific ...

----------- **Edit:**

Here is a minimal model as required. As I am a newbie in Tensorflow it is probably not really minimal nor efficient.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn as model_fn_lib


def get_inp():
    x_train = tf.constant([[[1], [2], [3]],
                           [[2], [3], [4]],
                           [[3], [4], [5]],
                           [[4], [5], [6]]],
                          dtype=tf.float32)
    y_train = tf.constant([[4],
                           [5],
                           [6],
                           [7]],
                          dtype=tf.float32)
    return x_train, y_train


def lstm_model(features, target, mode, params):
    x_ = tf.unstack(features, axis=0)

    # LSTM Layer and wrappers
    single_lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(params['hidden_size'],
                                          initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-2, 2))
    wrapper = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([single_lstm])
    output, layers = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(wrapper, x_, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear output layer to achieve the right output size
    output = tf.reshape(output, [features.get_shape().as_list()[0], -1], name='reshape')
    W = tf.get_variable("W",
                        [3 * params['hidden_size'], 1],
                        initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-2, 2),
                        dtype=tf.float32)

    b = tf.get_variable("b",
                        [1],
                        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0),
                        dtype=tf.float32)
    predictions = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(tf.matmul(output, W) + b), axis=1, name='unstack')

    predictions_dict = {"predictions": predictions}

    # Loss function
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(target, predictions)

    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss=loss,
                                               global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
                                               learning_rate=params["learning_rate"],
                                               optimizer=params["optimizer"],
                                               name='optimize_loss')

    return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(mode=mode,
                                   predictions=predictions_dict,
                                   loss=loss,
                                   train_op=train_op)


model_params = {'learning_rate': 0.01,
                'optimizer': 'Adam',
                'hidden_size': 2}

# Creates the estimator instance
regressor = learn.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model,
                            params=model_params,
                            config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=15))

regressor.fit(input_fn=lambda: get_inp(),
              steps=1)

print(regressor.get_variable_names())

# As suggested by Engineero
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    variable_names = [v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
print(variable_names)
```

Which outputs :

```
['W', 'b', 'global_step', 'optimize_loss/W/Adam', 'optimize_loss/W/Adam_1', 'optimize_loss/b/Adam', 'optimize_loss/b/Adam_1', 'optimize_loss/beta1_power', 'optimize_loss/beta2_power', 'optimize_loss/learning_rate', 'optimize_loss/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/biases/Adam', 'optimize_loss/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/biases/Adam_1', 'optimize_loss/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights/Adam', 'optimize_loss/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights/Adam_1', 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/biases', 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights']
[]
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without being able to see your code. Could you add a complete, minimal, self-contained model to ground the discussion?

Comment: I did, it's probably not very minimal though as my understanding of Tensorflow is still limited.

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all your trainable variable names:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)  # initialize things first
    variable_names = [v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
```

If you want to view the values of your variables, use something like (still inside your `with tf.Session()` group):

```
variable_values = [sess.run(v) for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
```

I like to look at the names and shapes of my variables before I start my training loop to make sure weights and biases are the sizes I expect:

```
variable_shapes = [v.get_shape() for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
for name, shape in zip(variable_names, variable_shapes):
    print('{}\nShape: {}'.format(name, shape))
# ... training loop starts later ...
```

Once you know the name of your variable, you can select it with something like:

```
var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables if v.name == expected_name][0]
```

And then I think you can apply your regularization directly to it from there.

Comment: As the code example I put in the question shows, 'variable_names' does not contain anything ... I think this is because I use an Estimator and not a custom model like in the Tensorflow tutorials. How may I access the variables in the Estimator model for use in regularization ?